How to output a list into columns while maintaining alphabetical sort?
I am trying to take a List of values which are sorted alphabetically.
And output a table with multiple columns.



col1
col 2
col 3




Anoint
Coup
Industrious


Balm
Deadpan
Minutiae


Chagrin





Depending on how large the list is and how many columns, I need to figure out how to maintain the alphabetical sort in each column then move the remaining into the next.
I've tried figuring out the rows by:
var rows = (int)Math.Ceiling(data.Count() / columns);
This would then fill each column by max rows first and the last column would be short.
Instead I'm trying to find a way to have the last row be truncated.

Edit: Found my Solution that works.
string[,]? GetResult(List<string> input, int numColumns)
{
    if (input == null) return null;
    if (numColumns < 1) numColumns = 1;

    double rowsRemainder = input.Count / (numColumns*1.0);
    int remainder = input.Count % numColumns;
    int numRows = (int)Math.Ceiling(rowsRemainder);
    string[,] result = new string[numRows, numColumns];
    int inputIndex = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < numColumns; col++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
        {
            if (row == (numRows-1) && col >= remainder) continue;

            result[row, col] = input[inputIndex];
            inputIndex++;
        }
    }

    var padLength = input.Max(x => x.Length) + 2;
    OutputValue(result, padLength);
    return result;
}


Please add the code you have currently written and explain why it doesn't work for you

It's not clear to me exactly what you are asking for here. Does this work? data.Order().Chunk(columns)? If you want to iterate on "rows", you can just iterate on each of the chunks produced by that call in order.

Yeah, it's not clear what you mean. The closest explanation is how to maintain the alphabetical sort in each column then move the remaining into the next, which doesn't register for me. Are you trying to get something like A B C </b> D E F </b> G H? Or maybe A D G </b> B E H </b> C F? (i.e., column-major or row-major ordering). Or are you trying to sort on a column?

It is modular arithmetic.  If you use Data.Count % columns you get the number of columns in the last row.  So if you get zero the last row contains all the columns.  If you get one than the last column is empty.  If you get two than the last two columns are empty.  If you get three than the last three columns are empty.

@jdweng Thanks! This is what I needed to make my solution work. I modified the answer from +Rufus L below to make my solution.

If you want to have the partially filled last row to be truncated, simply use integer division: int fullRows = input.Count / numColumns;. Then for (int i = 0; i < fullRows *  input.Count; i++) do int row = i % numColumns; and int column = i / numColumns;.

...or int i = row + fullRows * column; for column = [0 ... numColumns - 1] and row = [0 ... fullRows - 1].

Solution that worked for me is a modification from @Rufus L posted.
string[,]? GetResult(List<string> input, int numColumns)
{
    if (input == null) return null;
    if (numColumns < 1) numColumns = 1;

    double rowsRemainder = input.Count / (numColumns*1.0);
    int remainder = input.Count % numColumns;
    int numRows = (int)Math.Ceiling(rowsRemainder);
    string[,] result = new string[numRows, numColumns];
    int inputIndex = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < numColumns; col++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
        {
            if (row == (numRows-1) && col >= remainder) continue;

            result[row, col] = input[inputIndex];
            inputIndex++;
        }
    }

    var padLength = input.Max(x => x.Length) + 2;
    OutputValue(result, padLength);
    return result;
}


In this example, I'm storing the data in a 2d array of rows and columns, but the logic should be similar no matter how you're storing it. It's not clear how you're determining the number of columns, but for this example it's passed into the method along with the list.
There's probably a more straight-forward way to do this, but one idea is to do some calculations on the rows and columns based on the number of items in the list to determine the number of full rows and the number of full columns, as well as the total number of rows.
We can use these values to determine the index of the item to insert into our table:
string[,]? GetTable(List<string> input, int numColumns)
{
    if (input == null) return null;
    if (numColumns < 1) numColumns = 1;

    int numFullRows = input.Count / numColumns;
    int remainder = input.Count % numColumns;
    int numFullCols = remainder > 0 ? remainder : numColumns;
    int numRows = numFullRows + (remainder > 0 ? 1 : 0);

    string[,] result = new string[numRows, numColumns];

    if (input.Count == 0) return result;

    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < numColumns; col++)
        {
            // If this isn't a full column and we're on the last row, 
            // it's an empty cell so we can break
            if (col >= numFullCols && row == numRows - 1) break;

            // Calculate the index of the item for this cell based on 
            // the row and column values (and subtract one if this is
            // not a full column)
            int inputIndex = row + (numRows * col);
            if (col >= numFullCols) inputIndex--;

            result[row, col] = input[inputIndex];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

Usage:
var items = new List<string> { 
    "Anoint", "Balm", "Chagrin", "Coup", 
    "Deadpan", "Industrious", "Minutiae"};

// Get the list in the form of a table
var result = GetTable(items, 3);

// Output the items
var padLength = items.Max(x => x.Length) + 2;

for(int row = 0; row < result.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col<result.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        Console.Write($"{result[row, col]}".PadRight(padLength));
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

Output:


For some reason I am getting index out of range exceptions using this. I was able to find the solution by using your idea and modifying the code to get the desired results. Thanks!

@danewfie Great! I'd be interested to know what modifications you had to make. Will you let me know?

I modified the logic inside the for loop as it kept giving me an index exception. So I modified it so it only increments the inputIndex when its in a valid cell to populate. This way the index will always be within the range I want.
